# Google NearBy API usage and pricing

Tags: ios, quota, google-nearby

I am implementing Google's NearBy Messages API for a proximity based feature on my iOS app. I am trying to find out quota limit that I may need. This is the information provided on the developer console:

Queries per day 8,640,000 
Queries per 100 seconds per user 1,000 
Queries per 100 seconds 10,000

Can you please help me understand what a query refers to? When I make a successful scan and receive between 2 devices, I see # of requests go up by roughly 14-15. When reviewing queries per second - I see 18 - 25 queries.

Comment: Hi, I'm interested too, did you find out something?